# Coloring every second sub-layer in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

I'm working on a whiteboard app that included hierarchy.

So my question is: How can I color every second sub-layer in CSS (or if needed js)?

Example stying

```css
ul {
  width: 256px;
  min-height: 64px;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;
  background-color: blue;
}
/*FOLLOWING SHALL BE REPLACED BY AN SELECTOR OR JS-ALGORITHM*/

div>ul>ul,
div>ul>ul>ul>ul,
div>ul>ul>ul>ul>ul>ul,
div>ul>ul>ul>ul>ul>ul>ul>ul {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I aim to color are the divs in line 2 and 4 (and so on: 6, 8, 10,... if I would work with more sub-layers)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp should be like: nth-child(odd) {
    background: #colorcode;
}

Comment: @calinaadi this doesn't work here, since I want to select child in child in child... elements

Comment: @Paulie_D please refresh codepen example

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander again... this doesnt work here, If you think Im wrong, show me your example please

Comment: http://imgur.com/McAItP3 Here you see my aim, in more detail, but ATM its colored manually for 2 and 4, I want a selector for this

Comment: _obligatory "don't use w3schools" comment_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no CSS selector for that. You can however achieve it with a recursive function in JavaScript (jQuery):

```
colorList($('div > ul'));

function colorList($ul) {
    $ul.css({'backgroundColor': 'red'});

    var $nextElement = $ul.find('> ul > ul');
    if($nextElement.length) {
        colorList($nextElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are creating the HTML code dynamically, so it is easier to just add a class to the ``<ul>``, which needs to be styled.

Comment: yes, we will be doing this, so php will generate classes